# Laravel: Input Field generated from DB -> Handle them all in Controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a list of input fields in a form displayed for every entry in Database X.

To display it easier:

Table Device.
Table Settings (One Entry = One mroe input field / relationship with table device).

When a new devcie is added a User needs to enter all the settings. These settings will be saved in a third table (related to the `device`-table and the `settings`-table.

I added the input fields for the settings like this:

```
@foreach($pms as $pm)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $pm->name }}</th>
        <td>{!! Form::text($pm->id, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

How can I process them now the easiest way in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the blade you should define text fields like this:

```
@foreach($pms as $pm)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $pm->name }}</th>
        <td>{!! Form::text("texts[{$pm->id}]", null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

In a controller you can access them through `\Input::get('texts')` and iterate because it returns array.

Comment: Quick question. I called the array `pm` instead of texts. I check for settings not empty and create them (they have a own model. I need to access the id so p.ex `pm[16]` (i need the 16) and their respective value. Like this, http://pastebin.com/DjPgvTE8 nothing is saved, but no error is thrown. (edit: i added the save(), not working though)

Comment: @Scarwolf foreach($pm as $key=>$value) {...}

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.